# Does someting like AcceptRequestType exists in ASP.NET Core Web API?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I would like to have a single controller action to accept different types as request and I would like to have them automatically generated with Swashbuckle. There is possibility of annotating Web API method with Attribute `ProducesResponseType` on method of controller like this:

```
[HttpGet()]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(typeName))]
public Task<IActionResult> Method()
{
  //...
}
```

Does exists a similar option for request types? Something like this:

```
[HttpGet()]
[AcceptRequestType(typeof(concreteTypeName1))]
[AcceptRequestType(typeof(concreteTypeName2))]
public Task<IActionResult> Method(AbstractType model)
{
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following attribute:

```cs
[Consumes("application/json")]
```